# How does Sqoop append command will work in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I got one question on Sqoop --append command as we know append command will add a value to the existing table or record but in hadoop or hdfs update option is prohibited how does it work?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by update is prohibited. UPDATE in Hive started with version 0.14

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation,

> By default, imports go to a new target location. If the destination directory already exists in HDFS, Sqoop will refuse to import and overwrite that directory’s contents. If you use the --append argument, Sqoop will import data to a temporary directory and then rename the files into the normal target directory in a manner that does not conflict with existing filenames in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

in hadoop also we have a provision to update the file using "-appendtoFile" command , there it will append the data to existing data but file names will be diff.